# Open a .bar file in Blackberry Playbook Simulator

Tags: blackberry, flash-builder, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-playbook

Hi I have a early version of an Playbook app one of our developers made for us in Flash Builder. It is a .bar file.
I have installed all the required Abode and RIM SDK's, keys and simulator and can create an app myself in Flash Builder 4.5 which runs in debug mode in the simulator perfectly.

The problem is our developer has gone on holiday for a week and I want to test the app while he is away and give him feedback but I cant seem to open a single .bar file.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I assume you mean "install" a .bar file, since opening it (on your PC) is a simple matter of unzipping it.

To install/deploy to the simulator, you'd do this at the command line, where the SDK bin/ folder is in your PATH.

```
blackberry-deploy -installApp -device DEVIP -password PASS -package barfilename.bar
```

The DEVIP and PASS should be expanded to the device/simulator IP address and password, respectively.  The default (maybe only possible?) simulator password is "playbook".

You can include "-launchApp" in the above command to automatically launch the app too, but if you don't you merely click on its icon.  The simulator may still have a bug where the icon doesn't show up until you change categories back and forth, or pause for a moment.

Comment: Thanks for the response Peter. I will try your suggestion on my mac later today. I also have a Playbook now. Is it posible to run a .bar file signed by someone else on it? or does the .xml need to have the same author name, id etc. Sorry for the noobness but i've not developed for blackberry before and I am finding the process quite difficult

Comment: To find DEVIP in BB OS X, click the first icon on the status bar (top-right corner).

Comment: @Peter Hansen...Thanks a lot..your command line code helped me a lot...and I am able to get expected result..so Thank you so much...:)

Comment: I am not able to find correct bin/ folder , I am referring C:\bbndk\jre\bin , but not able to execute the command..

Comment: Peter, you can use whatever search facility your OS provides to find the file. The folder it's in is the bin/ folder you need. Look for "blackberry-deploy.cmd" on Windows, or "blackberry-deploy.sh" on the other systems, or just leave off the file extension.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can also refer this link: https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/using_the_tablet_simulator_1866980_11.html

Hope it will help you with more information.

Answer (score 0):

The instructions for BB10 simulator: https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/using_the_bb10_simulator_2008466_11.html