# Install .bar file in BB10 Virtual Machine

Tags: blackberry-playbook, blackberry-10

Hello Everybody ,
                 I am working on Application porting concept . Port Android Application to BB 10 & successfully generate BAR (Executable file in BB10 OS) file from the Android apk.
I am using Online Repacking tool for the conversion .
here is the link :-  https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/android/bpaa/
follow the process and get bar file from given APK.

Now My question is how I can run this .bar file into BB 10 Virtual Machine.
I got answer from the link ..
[Open a .bar file in Blackberry Playbook Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6320657/open-a-bar-file-in-blackberry-playbook-simulator)

but not able to implement properly.Please let me know how I can run .bar file format in Virtual Machine .

Comment: Are you getting any errors you could show? "not able to implement properly" is a bit vague.

Comment: @joachimIsaksson ..actually I don't know SDK bin/ folder path , I am refraining this C:\bbndk\jre\bin as a path and not able to execute   following command  "blackberry-deploy -installApp -device DEVIP -password PASS -package barfilename.bar"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't already, you'll need to download the [Command Line Tools for Android apps](http://developer.blackberry.com/android/tools/).

If you unzip the command line tools to a known location, the `blackberry-deploy` command is located in;

`<unzip location>\blackberry.tools.SDK\bin` (Windows)

or

`<unzip location>/blackberry.tools.SDK/bin` (Mac)

(the command itself is included in multiple SDKs, but you seem to currently be working with Android)